# How to include an index in a list generated by mapcar?

Tags: mapping

This statements generates a list of `(list filename buf)`,
How could this be written to include an index as well?

eg: `(list index filename buf)` where the index would be a counter, starting at zero, increment 1 for each item.

```el
(mapcar
  (lambda (buf) (list (buffer-file-name buf) buf))
  (seq-filter 'buffer-file-name (buffer-list))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
(let ((my-counter  0))
  (mapcar (lambda (buf) (list (cl-incf my-counter) (buffer-file-name buf) buf))
          (seq-filter 'buffer-file-name (buffer-list))))
```

Or if you want to use a global counter (e.g. for other purposes too):

```lisp
(defvar my-counter 0 "My wonderful counter.")

(mapcar (lambda (buf) (list (cl-incf my-counter) (buffer-file-name buf) buf))
        (seq-filter 'buffer-file-name (buffer-list))))
```

If you don't want to use `cl-incf` then use `(setq my-counter (1+ my-counter))`.

Comment: Updated question to clarify what the index is.

Comment: Can a locally defined variable be used (via let?) so it doesn't need to be global.

Comment: Note, I though it might be possible to use a sequence generator in this case and merge the two sequences.

Comment: What two sequences? But yes, lots of things are possible.

Comment: something like this: `(merge-two-sequences (sequence of items) (generate-range))`

Comment: Go for it. (But it's not part of this question...)

Comment: Right, a counter works too, I just though it would be cleaner to use a range, like Python's `enumerate` or `range` features.